# EF Core - how to clear object's id and its navigation properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Let's assume that I have an object and I would like to clear its id and all navigation properties. Is is possible by detach? If so, then how can I perform this operation in EF core?

```
class Car
{
     int Id {get;set;}

     int CarTypeId {get;set;}

     [ForeignKey(nameof(CarTypeId))]
     CarType CarType{get;set;}

     ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something like this recently. The normal DbContext does not have a detached method, so I added one.

```
public void Detach<T>(T entity)
    where T : class
{
    Entry( entity ).State = EntityState.Detached;
}
```

Next I made a method to detach and reset an entity. I made it specifically for one entity, but concept is like this.

```
public void DetachAndResetKeys(Car entity)
{
    // Load references if needed

    // Detach
    _dbContext.Detach( entity );
    // Reset Key. 0 equals not set for int key
    entity.Id = 0;

    entity.CarType = null;
}
```

Update: To reset keys on detach. If keys can be different types, need to handle that as well. Here only `int`

```
public void Detach<T>(T entity)
    where T : class
{
    Entry( entity ).State = EntityState.Detached;
    foreach(var prop in Entry( entity ).Properties) {
        if (prop.Metadata.IsKey()) {
            prop.CurrentValue = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was wondering if detach could automaticaly clear all ids or not. Because I need to clear all ids automatically in the object.

Comment: @Ellbar added a detach version that resets keys. I did not test it, but it should work. In the same manner you could reset your references etc.